# Question about discrete log - why can one attacker not solve for g but two colluders can?

Tags: broadcast-encryption

I'm reading about the broadcast encryption described in Fiat and Naor's paper, I screen grabbed the relevant part below.
My question is essentially:

If there's a secret:

$g^{abc}$ $mod$  $A$ (where $A=PQ$ (both sufficiently large primes))

why is it that one user who knows:

$g^d$ $mod$ $A$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $A$

could not calculate $g^{abc}$ $mod$ $A$ but when you add a second user who know $g^e$ $mod$ $A$, and $e$, they can then collude to calculate $g^{abc}$ $mod$ $A$ ?

Context is provided below.

[image: the 1-resilient scheme]

The full paper can be found [here](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs6204/Privacy-Security/Papers/Crypto/Broadcast-Encryption.pdf)

The paper states that one user not in the privileged set could not calculate the secret, but two colluding users could (and so they rate the scheme 1-resilient).

Comment: Isn't this question about roots, not logarithms?

Comment: That is true, it's about solving for the base not the exponent. Could you change the title to something you think makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that someone who just knows $g^d \bmod N$ and $d$, they cannot compute $g$ (because they don't know the factorization of $N$; hence this is the RSA problem); however, if they know $g^d \bmod N$ and $d$ and $g^e \bmod N$ and $e$, then (assuming $gcd(d, e) = 1$), they can (and once they have $g$, they can compute $g^{abc} \bmod N$).

That's because, since they know $d$ and $e$, they can compute two integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sd + te = 1$ (that's where the assumption that $gcd(d, e) = 1$ comes in; if that's not true, then no such $s$, $t$ will exist).  Once that have those two integers, they can compute $(g^d)^s \times (g^e)^t = g^{sd + te} = g^1 = g$, recovering $g$.  One of $s$ and $t$ will be negative; that's not an issue, as we can compute inverses modulo a number of unknown factorization.